# photo editing effect

Tags: photo-editing

what is that effect that makes it look like a camera was rotated 20 degrees or so while taking the shot? it makes it kind of rounded at the edges, like this:

[image]

Comment: Not sure this is on topic...

Comment: @Jay - I'm sure... it's not.

Comment: @John - OK, I actually *was* sure it wasn't on topic, but I was trying to be 'non-confrontational.' (Whatever that means)... :-)

Comment: it's photo editing....

Comment: sorry...at least its already answered and you can forget about it

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a radial blur.  In photoshop you'd select Filter > Blur > Radial Blur and select the "Spin" option (as opposed to "Zoom").

Comment: is it available in the GIMP?

Comment: In GIMP it is located under Filters > Blur > Motion Blur, where you then select 'Radial'.

Answer (score 4):

Radial blur.

It's available in most of photo editing software.

Answer (score 2):

To produce that image, it looks like a radial blur has been overlaid on top of the original image with partial transparency so that you still see the sharp details through the blur.

1. Duplicate the current layer
2. Set the new layer to 50% opacity
3. Add radial blur (a type of motion blur) to top layer

A radial blur on its own would be [blurry at the corner](http://blog.saintlondon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/radial_blur.jpg)s, but in the above [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bektb.jpg) it's still possible to read "search here" on the top right or "Canada College" on the top left.

Comment: thank you very much!! this was by far the most helpful answer